# Is there a way to copy a file to temp folder and then get the file itself not just the file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am uploading multiple files through a form and then iterating through each file and am creating a zero byte temp file and getting the file name using the **GetTempFileName**. Is there a way to copy the file itself not just the file name and the zero byte?. The code runs but i always get the zero byte file on the other end of my API which should happen. My code is like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocumentsAsync(Documents files)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> tempFilePath = new List<string>();
            List<string> fileName = new List<string>();

            foreach (var doc in files.documents)
            {
                tempFilePath.Add(Path.GetTempFileName());
                fileName.Add(doc.FileName);

            }

            MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var filePath = tempFilePath;

            string token = Token();
            List<FileStream> streams = new List<FileStream>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempFilePath.Count; i++)
                    {

                        var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath[i], FileMode.Open);
                        formData.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), fileName[i], fileName[i]);
                        streams.Add(fileStream);
                    }


                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(_configuration["Application:AppDomain"]) + "api/Document")
                    {
                        Content = formData
                    };

                    request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");

                    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                    streams.ForEach(stream =>
                    {
                        stream.Dispose();
                    });

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Handle success
                    }
                    //Handle failure

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle the exception
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can't you get the files sent from Request.Files?

Comment: On the API? i can get them but they are zero byte files meaning am not copying the actual file from the temp folder. Am looking for a way to copy the actual file from the temp folder not just the file name

Comment: [GetTempFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=net-6.0) Creates a uniquely named, **zero-byte** temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file.  You aren't copying the file to temp folder, So you cant

Comment: Exactly Sir. So am looking for a way to copy the file itself to the temp folder not just the name.

Comment: The argumets files of Type Documents are Word files? or what is the specification of Documents class?

Comment: The document class has strings like file name, ID and a string of IForm files called documents which is the variable am looping above. public IFormFile[] documents { get; set; } is where all the documents are being kept

Comment: Try if my answer works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the **actual** file to temp fileName if you want to access it later

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocumentsAsync(Documents files)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> tempFilePath = new List<string>();
        List<string> fileName = new List<string>();

        foreach (var doc in files.documents)
        {
            string fileTempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            tempFilePath.Add(fileTempFileName );
            fileName.Add(doc.FileName);
            using(Stream outStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileTempFilePath )))
            {
                doc.CopyTo(outStream);

            }

        }

        //Continue your code [...]
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Handle the exception
    }


}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am able to receive the full file on the other end. Just for posterity if anyone will have an error of the keyword File use the entire name System.IO.File.OpenWrite. Thank you